# Delay Function PHP

Tags: php, function, delay

please tell me how to make a delay function to delay functions!

```
DelayCommand(functionToDelay, Delaytime);
```

..? in php 5.3+

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function delayCommand($callback, $delayTime) {
    sleep($delayTime);
    $callback();
}
```

Comment: The problem with sleep though is that it affects the page on a global level even when it sits inside a function. This means you can't use this function in the middle of the page. Just to demonstrate my point, if you set the timer for 5 seconds and use the function in the middle of the page, the first half of the page would load but then the second half wouldn't load for 5 seconds. That draw back makes sleep seem like a pretty useless function to me.

Comment: same issue i have @DanielTonon

Answer (score 1):

This should work, consider switching out `sleep()` to `usleep()`.

```
function DelayCommand($functionToDelay, $delayTimeInSeconds) {
    sleep($delayTimeInSeconds);
    $functionToDelay();
}

DelayCommand(function() { echo "yes"; }, 5);
```

(Code is untested)

Answer (score 1):

```
function delayCommay($function, $nano){
    usleep($nano);
    $function();
}
```

Will do the trick however it is synchronous. So if you make a call to `delayCommand` it will delay your whole script until it has run the command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it done asynchronously, see my answer here: [Scheduling php scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526699/scheduling-php-scripts/5526797#5526797)

For your information, here's a list of related functions:

- `sleep()` / `usleep()` - Sleep for an amount of (micro)seconds.
- `time_sleep_until()` - Sleep until a timestamp.
- `time_nanosleep()` - Sleep for an amount of seconds and nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have for delaying a function in MS, Sleep and Usleep pause the execution of the whole script, this seems to work pretty well

```
    public function DelayTime($ms){ 
         $now = microtime();
         $finishtime = ($now + $ms);

         while($now < $finishtime){ 
             $now = time();
             if($now >= $finishtime){ break; }
         }
         return true;
     }
```