# After clicking submit button, I need to print two statements with some time gap/ pause between them

Tags: php, html

After I click the submit button, I need to print two different statements. For ex :

```
echo "Hello user";
```

and

```
echo "Nice to meet you !";
```

But after printing the first statement, I want to give it a few seconds of time before it prints the next statement.
Is there any predefined function to get such result ?
If not, how can we get a pause between them ?

Comment: No, there's no such function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay Function PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803756/delay-function-php)

Comment: You should do this with javascript

Comment: After each `echo`, flush the buffer to the browser, give a pause, send a second `echo` and then flush the buffer again. How to flush the buffer @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php and delay the PHP thread @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php